# How i can debug my xamarin forms application in my physical device over wi-fi?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a virtual machine that i run with rdp in my local pc. I'm developing a xamarin forms app in visual studio in that virtual machine. So I would debug the app in my psysical device. I tried with adb but it don't work cause I can't connect my device via usb to virtual machine. Any ideas??

Comment: you can connect ADB to a device over wifi

Comment: @Jason I can't connect my device with USB cable. So i can't use adb solution because it require that I connect my device via usb for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ADB port forwarder` can be used to connect your local adb client with a remote adb server.

This can help you solve your problem: https://bitbucket.org/chabernac/adbportforward/wiki/Home

Comment: Thanks my friend. You saved my precious time and my job! Great!

Answer (score 2):

Google just updated this from Android 11 onwards, so for any one using a newer device, you can follow these steps to setup your device to build and debug wirelessly using your wifi connection:

- On your Android 11 device, go to your Settings -> Tap on Advanced and go to the Developer options.
- Then tap on Wireless Debugging switch, and always allow wireless debugging for your personal wireless network in the popup dialog
- Then tap on the Wireless Debugging option and select “Pair device with pairing code” and it will give you a 6 digit code and IP address as you can see in the image
- There are many ways of doing pairing the phone to your computer. For the simplest one, inside Visual Studio, go to Tools -> SDK Command Prompt and type the IP address and port from your phone above into the terminaladb pair {ipaddress}:{port}.
- Then take the IP Address and port from the last screen and enter the following command adb connect {ipaddress}:{port}.

There’s a lot [more details in this article](https://prototypemakers.medium.com/wireless-build-debug-with-android-on-xamarin-is-officially-here-8110593b39cf?sk=9ae6ee95c3028232d21e699ee1f77163) Including limitations and a comparison with the iphone wireless debug feature